# Python: file copying to USB drive - threading slower than synchronous

Tags: python, multithreading, performance, usb

For testing purposes, I wrote a script that takes a list of files and then copies them do another location. I did this to compare synchronous code vs threaded code (on a Windows 10 machine).

When copying the files from the main drive to another location of the same drive, threading version increases speed significantly, as expected (since it is an IO bound operation).

However, when I copy the files from the main disk to a USB drive, then threading decreases the speed very significantly, which is weird.

Without even inspecting the code, which is fairly simple, is there a reason that writing-speed to USB disks cannot be increased with threads?

Comment: Imaging you have a narrow door (slow USB) and you want to get people through it. What works better: all persons go through the door in one line, or groups of ten storm the door at the same time?

Comment: Ok thanks, makes sense. I guess I'm astonished/surprised that USB is such a bottleneck.